# "Can't find template" error in Django

Tags: python, django

I just started learning Django. I followed the guide on the Django webpage, but still don't feel that understood it. So I decided to make something similar by myself. Basically I am making similar voting system as in guide, but a bit different. So I started doing it by reading some documentations and guide text. I created a generic listview to display index.html, which will show the list of votings. '

this is my views code:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'Vote/index.html'
    model = Type

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Type.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
```

here is my index.html code:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'Vote/style.css' %}" />
{% block content %}
    <h2>Votings</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for voting in object_list %}
            <li>{{ voting.Type_name }}</li>
        {% empty %}
            <li>Sorry, there are not votes.</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Models code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class Voted_Object(models.Model):
    Voted_Object_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Voted_Object_image = models.ImageField
    Voted_Object_rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Type(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField
    Type_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Urls code:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    #url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
   # url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/voting/$', views.VoteView.as_view(), name='voting'),
]
```

There is also settings for templates:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

this is my directory:
[image]

and finally this is the error:

TemplateDoesNotExist at /Vote/

> Vote/index.html, Vote/type_list.html Request Method:  GET Request
>   URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/Vote/ Django Version: 1.8.2 Exception
>   Type: TemplateDoesNotExist Exception Value:    Vote/index.html,
>   Vote/type_list.html Exception
>   Location: C:\Users\Vato\Envs\django_test_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py
>   in select_template, line 76 Python
>   Executable:   C:\Users\Vato\Envs\django_test_env\Scripts\python.exe
>   Python Version:   2.7.10 Python Path: 
>   ['C:\Users\Vato\PycharmProjects\Project3', 
>   'C:\Users\Vato\PycharmProjects\Project3', 
>   'C:\windows\SYSTEM32\python27.zip', 
>   'C:\Users\Vato\Envs\django_test_env\DLLs', 
>   'C:\Users\Vato\Envs\django_test_env\lib', 
>   'C:\Users\Vato\Envs\django_test_env\lib\plat-win', 
>   'C:\Users\Vato\Envs\django_test_env\lib\lib-tk', 
>   'C:\Users\Vato\Envs\django_test_env\Scripts', 
>   'C:\Python27\Lib',  'C:\Python27\DLLs', 
>   'C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk', 
>   'C:\Users\Vato\Envs\django_test_env', 
>   'C:\Users\Vato\Envs\django_test_env\lib\site-packages']

It asks for 2 templates one index.html which I have and I wrote and second for type_list.html

I think the error is caused by missing file of type_list.html, but I don't get why django asks me for that template. **Where in the code do I specify the need for it?** and **How can I fix it so that the program will get votes from database and display them on index?**

as I researched and as I understand second template is looked because of model(Type)-to lower case and _list ending for some reason. it is made somewhere automatically, but I don't understand it.

I am not sure in my code, cause much is copied from documentations, but as I thought it should have worked without the second(type_list) template. Sorry for the long post. Thought shouldn't miss any code.

If you have any suggestions for the better way of learning django please feel free to comment.

Comment: Have you added the application in installed app list?

Comment: Yes I definetly have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `'DIRS': [BASE_DIR],` but your templates are not in BASE_DIR, they are in BASE_DIR/templates. You should have:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

Comment: It worked! thanks a lot! Do you have any tips for learning django?